# Let K ⊂ R consists of 0 and the numbers 1 /n for n = 1 , 2 ,... .Prove that K is compact directly from the definition (without Heine-Borel theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here is my idea:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$, so $0$ is a limit point of the set K. If $0$ is a l.p, there for all neighbourhoods $N_r(0)$ there is a point y such that,y $\in N_r(0)$ and $y \in K$. We know as well, that open neighbourhoods consists of infinitely many points. So one neighbourhood covers infinitely many points in interval K. The rest part is finite - which can be cover by finite subcover in various way.

This is my rough idea. What I want to ask you is to check, if i am going into the right direction. If yes - what should I add to my idea.
If I am wrong - tell me the direction(hint), which should I use.

Comment: You can't say it much better. The idea is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good. I outline your proof:

let $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I}G_i$, where the sets $G_i$ are open.

There is $i_0 \in I$ such that $0 \in G_{i_0}$. Since $G_{i_0}$ is open, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $1/n \in G_{i_0}$ for $n >N$.

Furthermore, there are $i_1,...,i_n \in I$ with

$1/j \in G_{i_j}$ for $j=1,2,..,N$.

Then we have: $K \subseteq \bigcup_{j=0}^NG_{i_j}$.

Thus we have proved: each open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover of $K$.