# Is $K$ is compact ? Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis

Taken from Rudin books

Let $K ⊂ \mathbb{R}$ consists of $0$ and the numbers $1 /n$ for $n = 1 , 2 ,... $.Prove that $K$ is compact directly from the definition (without Heine-Borel theorem)

**My attempt** : I found the  answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2413122/557708).But im not satisfied with this answer

**My thinking** : I can make $$K=\{ 1, \frac{1}{2},......, \frac{1}{N-1}\} \cup \{0, \frac{1}{N} , \frac{1}{N+1},....\}$$

$$K=\underbrace{\{ 1, \frac{1}{2},......, \frac{1}{N-1}\}}_{\text{finite}} \cup \underbrace{\{0, \frac{1}{N} , \frac{1}{N+1},....\}}_{\text{infinite}}$$

we know that  $$\text{finite} \cup \text{infinite} = \text{infinite}$$

this  implies  that  $K$ doesn't contain finite subcover $\implies$  $K$  is not compact

Comment: Yes, $K$ is compact. You seem to have some misconceptions about which objects in the definition of compactness are finite.

Comment: If that argument worked, $\Bbb N$ would be compact too.

Comment: Any open neighborhood of $0$ contains all but finite members of $K$. Hence an arbitrary open cover has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $K$ is compact.  When we talk about whether a subcover is finite or infinite, we're talking about the *number of open sets* in the subcover, not whether any of those sets are themselves finite or infinite.  Your proposed cover has two open sets, so it is itself a finite subcover (because two is a finite number).